# Is it possible to force the device's date to test local notifications?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, testing, uilocalnotification

I am creating a `UILocalNotification` with a particular date.

I want to test the reminders that I set for different days. I also want to see if the repetition feature works. Is it possible to force the current time to different date and time so I can see whether it works?

Comment: This is a question about how your iOS device works, not about programming.

Comment: @matt Convenience when testing would seem to be part of programming - why do you believe this should be closed as off-topic?

Comment: @Undo is obviously right, I have no idea why you find it as of topic while the question was about testing a program with code.

Answer (score 4):

Well one way that I used to do it is to actually change the time and date on my iPhone itself through the Settings app.

If you don't know where to do this, [here's a wikihow article](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Date-and-Time-on-the-iPhone).

If you pass the time/date when the notification is supposed to go off, your iPhone will automatically make it go off.

Comment: **If you pass the time/date when the notification is supposed to go off, your iPhone will automatically make it go off.** where this is written in documentation?

Answer (score 2):

As David pointed out, you have to check by changing the date and time on your phone. But I would also like to point out something.

The default `timeZone()` of a notification is set according to your location. So even if you manually change the device date and time, the notification will not fire up. For it to work properly you need to set the `timeZone()` to `systemTimeZone()`. You can try this:

```
    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: What happens if I go to different timezone ? then one it was create at ?

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I have noticed, is that testing local notifications is impossible by setting the date forward to the exact date and time they need to fire. The way that I've approach this is by setting the time to one minute prior to the expected time that it needs to fire, and waiting out the 60 seconds to see it appear. Hope this advice helps :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable automatically time in setting
2. Run code add local notification(comp.timeZone = TimeZone.current)
3. Change time in setting to a time before your notification fire time
4. Wait until the fire time

Comment: I don't understand why we have to Timezone , could you brief please ?